# Qt 5.4 windows msvc x64 mysql driver not found

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt, 64-bit

I compiled an application in windows with Qt msvc x64 and deploy it using windeployqt.exe but when i compile code or run created exe i getting this error:
[Mysql Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UHWj.png)

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("market");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("1501");

if(!db.open())
{
   QMessageBox::critical(this,"HATA","Database bağlantısı sağlanamadı!"+db.lastError().text());
}
```

Only getting this mysql error other things work fine.What can i do?

Comment: Is there a sqldrivers folder in the same folder that contains your executable?

Comment: yes windeployqt.exe added sqldrivers folders in my apps directory but not working

Comment: Is the mysql dll inside that folder?

Comment: yes i added  myself

Comment: but now working :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the architecture of dll mysql x86 x64
I had the same problem, my OS W7 x64, I solved it copying the x86 dll from another install, I can send it to you by email